# Is there in TypeScript a way to use "extends T" as a type?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

#### Problem

I want to define a person with a pet that is something that **extends** `Animal`, and is not just an `Animal`:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  pet: extends Animal  //I'm looking for something that would work here
}
```

#### What I tried

So let's say we have these interfaces:

```js
interface Animal {
  name: string
}

interface Fish extends Animal {
  swim: () => void
}

interface Bird extends Animal {
  fly: () => void
}
```

###### 1. use the parent type

I know I can do:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  pet: Animal // Not what I want, because it needs to be only things that extend Animal
}
```

But that would hinder inference. Because if `pet` is not a `Fish`, it should be a `Bird`. But this way it can just as well be a plain `Animal`.

###### 2. union type

To only use types that extends `Animal`, I can pick them myself with a union type:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  pet: Fish | Bird // Not what I want, because I would need to update it with new animals
}
```

But if I want to create more animal types, I would have to update `Person` every time.

For example, if I add:

```js
interface Mole extends Animal {
  dig: () => void
}
```

I want `Person` to automatically accept `Mole` as a pet without explicitly adding it by changing `pet: Fish | Bird` to `pet: Fish | Bird | Mole`.

#### Summary

I'm looking for a way that accepts **anything that extends** `Animal`, but **not the parent** `Animal` itself, without having to update it every time a new animal comes along.
How can I do this in Typescript?

###### Note

I do not need `Animal` to exist as an interface, but it would be nice if it can stay an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where generics come in to the picture:

```
interface Person<T extends Animal> {
  name: string
  pet: T
}

let personWithBirdPet: Person<Bird>;
let personWithFishPet: Person<Fish>;
let personWithMolePet: Person<Mole>;
```

Generics are kind of like "type arguments", much in the same way as you can define "value arguments" for functions (`function(foo, bar) {}`) we can define "type arguments" called generics for most type structures (including function `function<A, B>(foo: A, bar: B) {}`, and interfaces as you can see above).

When using generics we can apply constraints to the generics, by using the `extends` keyword. For example `function<A extends number>(value: A) {}` would be pretty much the same as writing `function(value: number) {}`. The version using generics is more powerful, but also more verbose. In this simple `function` example using generics would be overkill. However in your `interface` case, using generics would be exactly what you need.

### Bear in mind the duck-typing

Since typescript is duck-typed (if it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, then it is a duck). You can get some unexpected behavior that you need to be aware of.

For instance, you can have a person with a generic animal as a pet:

```
let personWithGenericPet: Person<Animal>;
```

..or you can have a person with a pet that doesn't "extend" animal, but looks like an animal:

```
let personWithStrangePet: Person<{ name: 'bob' }>;
```

..and speaking of which, a `Person` looks like an animal, so you can have a person with a person as a pet:

```
let personWithPersonPet: Person<Person<Animal>>;
```

These are not issues caused by generics, but are issues that are core to how typescript works.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuQgX0MNElkRQBCwKABNkEAB6QQI2mgzY8+Tj2jwkyAGLBaAC3FSIMueiy4CK8Gv7IAsgHscKSdNnyzSztyt8NABWhaexAAHgAVA1cTBVwAPgJiMgpqOgZmRIAHCDAaMI4uJzBkLKggkAB1YDBdIVEAnOQA0uCQ2pFYtkLiwODK6u09epomspCB3Q7CLpKyvt0HJyHGntCFiEnCAHpNgEJkABEAVQBhAGkAWjCATT8ASQA5AHFkctQAJXuHx6ns7uaKqq6R5GaDABBLEYtUyKSbTFZzADKDDgICYEAhKxC+CSlBoAHIAEb2Al45DsWG-Ga9QGQkAY-4hWkhaFxDpAA)

Comment: As a result, I now need to provide a type argument everywhere I already used `Person` as a type before. But I guess I could (ab)use `Person<Animal>` there... Also, I'm weighing that extra work for previous and future `Person` typings against just using `pet: Fish | Bird | Mole` anyway. It seems to be a bit more practical in my code base as long as `Person` is the only thing that needs to be updated when more `Animal`s are added.

Comment: @NeeL If you are going to insert `Person<Animal>` everywhere, then you could add a default value for the generic instead (`interface Person<T extends Animal = Animal>`, and use it simply as `Person`). That way you don't need to update it everywhere.

Comment: I just realised that would break type inference, right? [In this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) you can do `pet.fly()` in the else branch, but If I default to `Animal` I would first need to establish that it is actually a `Bird` even though we know it's not a `Fish`.

Comment: @NeeL yes, that would break inference. If you need inference to work out of the box then you need to keep sending the generic (`T` in my answer) down through each function that relies on the `Person`. For example have a look at this random [ts-playrgound](https://shorturl.at/anoxQ) i wrote a while back.

Comment: Oof... more reason for me to just use a union type then. Thanks for your effort, your extensive answer and your replies! Btw, your shortUrl doesn't work for me, but I get the gist.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work ?

```
interface Person<T extends Animal> {
    name: string;
    pet: T;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! I didn't think of using generics on that level. Although you were 5 seconds earlier then @Olian04. I did accept their answer because it provides a small example and explanation that can be useful for future visitors to this question.